# CurrentUser.Name different on dev to test?

Tags: development, user-profile

Locally (during development) CurrentUser.Name brings back a nicely formatted first name and surname: "Dee Mac". On test it brings back "DOMAIN\DeeMaC".

Is there anyway I can ensure I'm gettin a 'display  friendly' name on test and production? Why has it changed? Thanks a lot.

EDIT: Could it be that the Name property will retrieve the LoginName if name is not populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names fall back, you have preferred name, First Name, User Name, Login Name etc.

You pretty much answered it for yourself :)